# How to delete nodes without taking a lot of time?

Tags: 7, performance

My site has about 200 000 nodes. When I want to delete let say 200 nodes it takes about 2hr. I have also installed commerce module, views and a lot of the usual modules. What can I do to speed things up?

Comment: How are you deleting your nodes right now? From the `admin/content` screen?

Comment: Run it on better equipment; other than that you'll probably need to dig into the core code and optimise anything you can to mitigate the lack of resources

Comment: Running entity_delete ops is heavy if you have a lot of things acting on this event like contrib code or rules.

Answer (score 4):

Usually I use 2 approach from the command line. If you call a page from the browser to accomplish the task this will use more time and resources.

**1. You can create your own module named `drush_delete`**

Inside the `drush_delete.drush.inc` file put this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * The Drush Delete drush commands.
 */

/**
* Implements hook_drush_command().
*/
function drush_delete_drush_command() {
  $items['node-delete'] = array(
    'description' => dt("Delete nodes."),
    'aliases' => array('nd'),
    'arguments' => array(
      'nids' => dt('The nids of the nodes to delete'),
    ),
    'examples' => array(
      'drush node-delete 1' => dt('Delete the node with nid = 1.'),
      'drush node-delete 1 2 3' => dt('Delete the nodes with nid = 1, 2 and 3.'),

    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for the node-delete command
 */
function drush_drush_delete_node_delete() {
  $nids = func_get_args();
  $nids = array_filter($nids, 'is_numeric');
  $nids = array_map('intval', $nids);
  $nids = array_unique($nids);
  $nids = array_values($nids);
  $cant = count($nids);

  if ($cant > 0) {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);

    drush_print(dt("Deleted nodes:"));
    drush_print(implode(' ', $nids));
  }
  else {
    drush_set_error('DRUSH_ERROR_CODE', dt("You must enter at least one nid"));
  }
}
```

Install the module, run `drush cc drush` to clear the drush cache and use the command like this:

To delete a node use:

```
drush node-delete 1
drush nd 1
```

To delete multiple nodes use:

```
drush node-delete 1 2 3
drush nd 1 2 3
```

***EDIT:*** I just remeber that I have a collection of drush commands in github at https://github.com/adrian-cid/drush_commands.

**2. You can use the [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) module**

Deleting node with nid 1 and 2

```
drush entity-delete node 1 2
```

Deleting all the nodes:

```
drush entity-delete node
```

Deleting all the articles nodes:

```
drush entity-delete node --bundles=article
```

Comment: This is a better approach. With so many nodes, I would probably create a VBO action "mark node to be deleted" - which creates a job via QueueAPI, and the drush command pulls from that queue and deletes each flagged node. Then set up a cron job for every X minutes to call that function.

Comment: @Kevin nice approach, can you write an answer about how to do this please, I'm interested in test it.

Comment: Not sure of code offhand, but, if you can create a custom VBO action, that action will create jobs in the job queue via QueueAPI. Every job that is processed contains a callback, which is where you would delete the node. See this article for an example: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/handling-long-running-background-tasks-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to speed things up by using [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7.x). You can create a simple script in your drupal installation path which then would be executed either using the command line or through a http 'POST' request:

```
/** bootstrap drupal **/
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Array of nid for each node to delete
$nids = array();

// Check if script running from cli or not
$isCli = defined('STDIN');
if ($isCli && $argc === 2) {
  $nids = explode(',', $argv[1]);
}
// Check if script is invoked using a 'POST' request
if (!$isCli && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['nids'])) {
    $nids = explode(',', $_POST['nids']);
  }
}

if (count($nids)) {
  // make sure the script does not timeout
  set_time_limit(0);

  try {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Of course you need to supply the nids for all nodes that you wish to delete.

The fastest way would also be to run this script from the command line:

```
php delete-nodes.php 1,2,3,4
```

You could also make a 'POST' request, for instance using curl:

```
curl https://example.com/delete-nodes.php -d 'nids=1,2,3,4'
```

Comment: this is in a page and the page will be called from the browser?

Comment: Yes this would be put in a stand alone file placed in the root of the drupal installation. Of course all nids must be added and I'm not sure this would really would speed things up, but I think it is worth a try.

Comment: I think that you need to add this info in yout question and how run the script from the command line because if you run this from the broswer will be more slow that from the command line.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer - It is an answer not a question =) And you don't need to run it from the command line.

Comment: @ yes is true in your answer, sorry, just I think that you can call your script from the command line and this will be better, is just a suggestion.

Comment: This is not going to work well. Instead, you could use drush to do long running tasks. Plus not a repeatable solution.

Answer (score 0):

D7:

I would also use `node_delete_multiple()`. This is also the way that Devel generate handles it, https://git.drupalcode.org/project/devel/-/blob/57e32c63089216da92efe811212bd4f6026ba307/devel_generate/devel_generate.inc#L605-625

```
/**
 * Handle the devel_generate_content_form request to kill all of the content.
 * This is used by both the batch and non-batch branches of the code.
 *
 * @param $num
 *   array of options obtained from devel_generate_content_form.
 */
function devel_generate_content_kill($values) {
  $results = db_select('node', 'n')
              ->fields('n', array('nid'))
              ->condition('type', $values['node_types'], 'IN')
              ->execute();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $nids[] = $result->nid;
  }

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
    drupal_set_message(t('Deleted %count nodes.', array('%count' => count($nids))));
  }
}
```

D8:

The Devel module also has a devel_generate submodule. It has a `contentKill()` function,

First part is just querying the nodes.

```
  /**
   * Deletes all nodes of given node types.
   *
   * @param array $values
   *   The input values from the settings form.
   */
  protected function contentKill(array $values) {
    $nids = $this->nodeStorage->getQuery()
      ->condition('type', $values['node_types'], 'IN')
      ->execute();

    if (!empty($nids)) {
      $nodes = $this->nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
      $this->nodeStorage->delete($nodes);
      $this->setMessage($this->t('Deleted %count nodes.', ['%count' => count($nids)]));
    }
  }
```

Source, https://git.drupalcode.org/project/devel/-/blob/b38337acfc47a3b208c46c98b8d9d219779f98fb/devel_generate/src/Plugin/DevelGenerate/ContentDevelGenerate.php#L571-587

If for some reason it doesn't fit in memory, just use `array_chunk()`

Quick notes,

- `nodeStorage` is `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface`
- `setMessage` is here https://git.drupalcode.org/project/devel/-/blob/b38337acfc47a3b208c46c98b8d9d219779f98fb/devel_generate/src/DevelGenerateBase.php#L141-158

Instead of the script on another answer, I would just add a function on a custom module and call it with `drush ev function_name();`